# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT Predicate SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, predicate

For some reason, I am getting "SGNL SGBRT" error where I assign a value at predicate. What is the reason of this and how can I overcome this problem?

```
struct SearchView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest var reminder: FetchedResults<CDReminder>
    @Binding var searchText: String

init(searchText: Binding<String>) {
    self._searchText = searchText
    var predicate : NSPredicate?
    predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", searchText as! CVarArg) // SGNL SGBRT ERROR
    self._reminder = FetchRequest(
        entity: CDReminder.entity(),
        sortDescriptors: [],
        predicate: predicate
        )
}
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            SearchBar(text: $searchText)
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, viewContext)
            List{
                ForEach(reminder, id: \.self){ reminder in
                    DatedReminderCell(reminder: reminder, isSelected: false, onComplete: {})
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: insted of searchText use searchText.wrappedValue. Also no need to cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property wrapper `@Binding` has the following semantics:

- `self._searchText` (same as `$searchText`) represents the struct `Binding<String>`, the two-way binding.
- `self.searchText` (same as `self._searchText.wrappedValue`) represents the wrapped string value.

It's a bit similar to a RawRepresentable String enum. You need the `rawValue` rather than the enum case.

So the correct syntax is either

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", self.searchText)
```

or

```
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS %@", self._searchText.wrappedValue)
```

As `String` conforms to the `CVArg` protocol a (bridge) cast is not needed. A force cast is wrong anyway.

Comment: I edited my code according to your answer. Now, in my RemindersApp.swift file I get "Thread 1: "unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (name CONTAINS \"\")"" error

Comment: if I remove predicate line from my code then I do not get any errors and all the reminders are coming in a sheet view

Comment: It looks like you have to filter the *empty string* case: `if !self.searchText.isEmpty { predicate = NSPredicate(format: ...)}`

Comment: it solved the problem but it does not check my searchText. It shows all the reminders whatever I type inside the searchBar

Comment: Did you check that `searchText` contains a non-empty string when `searchView` is being initialized?